# Guardar una matriz como archivo .csv en Python

Tags: python, csv, matrices

Voy a generar una matriz de 3000 x 14 en Python y después quiero guardarla en un archivo, estoy usando el comando:

```
import numpy as np

tabla = np.random.random((3000,14))

np.savetxt('tabla.dat', tabla)
```

Esto funciona bien. El motivo que me trae aquí es que quisiera guardarla en un archivo .csv y he probado esto:

```
import csv
with open('tabla.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(tabla)
```

Pero no funciona, el error que tira es:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Y genera un archivo que está vacío, supongo que como salta el error, crea el archivo, pero no llega a escribirlo.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchísimas Gracias.

Lucia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que, aunque no lo comentas, debes estar usando Python 3.x pero usas un método propio de Python 2.x. Debes abrir el archivo en modo texto no en modo binario como lo estás haciendo ahora. Por otro lado debes especificar el parámetro `newline` dandole un string vacío para que no te cree una nueva linea por defecto entre cada fila de la matríz. El código debe ser:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

tabla = np.random.random((3000,14))

with open('tabla.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(tabla)
```

Para más información te dejo el enlace a la documentación oficial del [módulo csv en Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

**Edición:**

Respondiendo al comentario de como añadir títulos a las columnas del csv, ten en cuenta que un csv no tiene headers intrínsecamente, es simplemente eso, un archivo con datos separados por comas. Lo que se hace es usar la primera línea del csv para los encabezados. Para ello simplemente añadimos una fila inicial nada más creado el csv y antes de guardar el resto de filas:

```
import csv

tabla = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
headers = ('Imagen', 'Distorsión', 'Nivel')

with open('tabla.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(tabla)
```

A la hora de leer los datos simplemente especificamos que esa primera linea contiene los nombres (algunas librerías ya intentan hacer esto por defecto), por ejemplo usando `DictReader` de la misma librería podemos cargar los datos y acceder por el nombre de las columnas:

```
with open('tabla.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Imagen'])
```

Nos imprime la primera columna (llamada 'Imagen'):

> 1
>   4
>   7

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Sabes cómo puedo ponerle nombres a las columnas de mi tabla? Por ejemplo, la primer columna debe tener el rótulo Imagen, la segunda Distorsión, la tercera Nivel y así...

Comment: @Lucy_in_the_sky_with_diamonds simplemente agregalo como primera fila del csv teniendo los nombres en un iterable. He editado la pregunta, mira a ver si responde a tu duda. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente! Gracias!

Comment: Bellisimo, pero una pregunta, se puede tambien agregar las nombres a las filas?, lo podria hacer pero abriendo y cerrando el archivo creo y eso no estaría bien, si es posible, nos puede explicar? Gracias.

Comment: @Joel si te refieres a añadir un índice a las filas, simplemente es añadirlo como primera columna, dejando vacía esa posición en el header `headers = ('', 'Imagen', 'Distorsión', 'Nivel')`. El parseo correcto luego depende del código/programa encargado de la lectura del csv. Si no das con la forma o tienes dudas te invito a [crear una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explicando tu problema, de qué partes y qué quieres conseguir para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.